# How to check if X server is running?

Tags: linux, x11, xserver

Is there any way to find out if the current session user is running an Xserver (under Linux) ?

I've started off with things like:

```
ps -e | grep X
```

but this doesn't work always

and one more thing I tried is checking the `$DISPLAY` variable

Are there any other ways to check this?

EDIT:

Some people suggested using the `$DISPLAY` variables but what if the user fiddles with this variable ? what if he tries to do something and changes this variable and then when I check it, it no longer reflects an accurate state of the system.
Is there no specific way to do this that will always return a correct answer ?

I found that it can be done programmatically thus:

```
#include <X11/Xlib.h> 
int main()
    { exit(XOpenDisplay(NULL) ? 0 : 1);  } 

$ gcc -o xprobe xprobe.c -L/usr/X11R6/lib -lX11
```

But I am looking for a script way.

Comment: why doesn't "ps -e | grep X" always work?

Comment: And why doesn't $DISPLAY work?

Comment: @stephendl:I found that in some situations X is running but the user is connected through a terminal with no X
@matthew: What if the user fiddles with this variable and it no longer reflects the actual state of the system ?

Comment: Just a nit pick: there's no point in calling exit() in your C program to test for X, just return the status and you're done.

Comment: And to nitpick a little more... the XOpenDisplay makes use of the DISPLAY environment variable internally.

Comment: @RomanM: I recommend you accept the answer with the most votes i.e. the one with `xset`.

Comment: @RomanM so you do not want to know, if X is running. You want to know, if the current login is connected to X server. Please change your question to indicate what you are really asking.

Comment: There are several different questions here, and different answers below answer different questions: 1) is the host running an X server 2) is the 'current session user' (whatever that is; probably refers to the Linux user running a shell, from which the inquiry will be made) running an X session 3) is this very shell session connected to a running X server and able to use it.

Answer (score 86):

I often need to run an X command on a server that is running many X servers, so the `ps` based answers do not work. Naturally, `$DISPLAY` has to be set appropriately. To check that that is valid, use `xset q` in some fragment like:

```
if ! xset q &>/dev/null; then
    echo "No X server at \$DISPLAY [$DISPLAY]" >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

### EDIT

Some people find that *xset* can pause for a annoying amount of time before deciding that `$DISPLAY` is not pointing at a valid X server (often when tcp/ip is the transport). The fix of course is to use *timeout* to keep the pause amenable, 1 second say.

```
if ! timeout 1s xset q &>/dev/null; then
    ⋮
```

Comment: I think this is "better" than using `xprop` and `xdpyinfo` since `xset` produces less output for `/dev/null` to eat. The OP should accept this answer.

Comment: When there is no X-Server running at all at the $DISPLAY address, `xset` just hangs, indeed as to all the X-commands.  Is there a way to set a time-out?

Comment: @will This hang won't be specific to `xset`. Any X program will suffer it. The hang depends on the X transport. If you have `DISPLAY=:1` say, this implies tcp port 6001. You may have some rouge process listening. My `xset` returns immediately when nothing is listening.

Comment: This is good, but why is it noisy?  I keep getting "connect /tmp/.X11-unix/X1: No such file or directory", even if I redirect stdout and stderr to /dev/null.  I strace'd it, and it doesn't appear to be getting written by xset.  I also strace'd the relevant sshd and it doesn't seem to be writing it either. xset, xdpyinfo and the test program in the original question all output this useless error message.

Comment: @dstromberg This is a pretty inappropriate place for this question! Nevertheless: it looks to me like you are ssh-ing from a local machine _local_ into a remote machine _remote_, with X-forwarding turned on in your _ssh_. The problem is that the original _ssh_ command needs access to a working X server, and it looks to me that you have a badly set `$DISPLAY` on _local_. What then happens is you run an X command on _remote_. _Ssh_ tunnels the X protocol back to _local_ which fails (due to the dodgy `$DISPLAY`) and _ssh_ prints the message.

Comment: @bobbogo I'm not sure, from my question, why you'd think I didn't know that.  My question is: Why can't I redirect the error message somewhere?  Not: Why is this an error condition?  Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56825547/why-does-x11-output-connect-tmp-x11-unix-x1-no-such-file-or-directory .  It's a surprisingly complex issue.

Comment: This takes 35 seconds in my WSL2 (Windows Subsystem for Linux) to finish when the X server is stopped. Is it any faster (instantaneously) way just to check if the X server is available? Thx.

Comment: @Gerard Which X server are you using, and what protocol are you talking to it with (i.e., what is your `$DISPLAY` set to)?

Comment: Hi @bobbogo I'm trying with `MobaXterm` and I set DISPLAY to this (which give me access from Windows): `export DISPLAY="$(/sbin/ip route | awk '/default/ { print $3 }'):0"`. I need to run `xmodmap` several times on shell startup (.profile) which takes a lot to answer if X server is down. I just want to add a guard in the script to prevent it. The guard is about test if X-server is running.

Comment: @Gerard A comment stream is not the place to dicuss this. I think you need to raise a question. You have not explcitly answered my question about `$DISPLAY`, but it looks as though you may be connecting to the XServer over tcp/ip. WSL2 does some interesting network translation, and that may be where your problem lies.

Comment: I think [`xhost`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/338862) is the better option. Especially if you're concerned with how much `/dev/null` eats.

Answer (score 22):

$DISPLAY is the standard way.  That's how users communicate with programs about which X server to use, if any.

Comment: but what if the user fiddles with this variable ? what if he tries to do something and changes this variable and then when I check it, it no longer reflects an accurate state of the system. Is there no concrete way to do this?

Comment: If I set $DISPLAY, it's because I want your program to go to a different display.  What exactly is your use case where you want to second-guess the user's explicit configuration?  Do you avoid using $HOME in case the user "fiddles" with that, too?  Where does it end?

Comment: i don't want to second guess, just bullet-proof. The use case is for a driver installer, one of the prerequisites is having x running.
And I wouldn't avoid using $HOME but ill check it points to an exsisting directory first just in case ^^

Comment: Which X server, exactly, do you want to access?  I've many times had to install drivers on remote systems.  Also, in POSIX XOpenDisplay(NULL) is defined to simply read $DISPLAY, so at best it sounds like you're counting on nonstandard behavior.

Comment: There is not particular X I want to detect, my installer just needs to know that the user is running it with one present.

Comment: I mean, if there's one running on localhost but they set $DISPLAY to another server because they're logged in remotely, do you still want the "local" one?  What if there's more than one local one?  I don't know how you'd detect that, or why you'd want to.  $DISPLAY exists for a reason.

Comment: Could you elaborate your answer for users not from the Linux world? What is $DISPLAY? How to use it?

Comment: I *think* @Ken means for us to say `echo $DISPLAY` but I'm not 100% sure what the expected output should be.

Comment: Under Windows (WSL), I want to test whether X is already running or not. In other words, I want to test BECAUSE I want to set DISPLAY. I may rephrase DISPLAY is set by something that assumes it knows X is running, it has nothing to do with the fact it is actually running.

Answer (score 9):

One trick I use to tell if X is running is:

telnet 127.0.0.1 6000

If it connects, you have an X server running and its accepting inbound TCP connections (not usually the default these days)....

Comment: I guess at present, security-conscious systems would not have the `telnet` command available.

Comment: Security-conscious systems won't be listening on a TCP port either, but would be restricted to Unix domain sockets, further invalidating this method.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `xdpyinfo` (can be installed via `apt-get install x11-utils`).

Answer (score 8):

I use

```
pidof X && echo "yup X server is running"
```

pgrep and $DISPLAY are other options.

Other considerations:

su then $DISPLAY will not be set. Things that change the environment of the program running can make this not work.

I don't recommand ps -e | grep X as this will find procX, which is not the X server.

Comment: Isn't this the same as ps -e | grep X ?
AFAIK pidof just an alias for killall5 and is not always defined on all systems

Comment: From man pidof:
"pidof is actually the same program as killall5; the program behaves according to the name  under  which it is called."

pidof behaves differently than killall5. If your using an old old unix system it may not be there.

Comment: But the same thing can be said about old unix systems regarding about a million things.

Answer (score 6):

```
xprop -root &> /dev/null
```

...is my tried & true command to test for an "X-able" situation. And, it's pretty much guaranteed to be on any system running X, of course, the command fails if not found anyways, so even if it doesnt exist, you can pretty much assume there is no X either. (thats why I use &> instead of >)

Comment: Re `&>` for use in shell scripts running under `dash` which does not support `&>`, one can use `>/dev/null 2>&1`.

Comment: On cygwin a typical way to install X is install the package `xinit`.  So, `xprop` is not installed automatically as it is not a dependency.

Comment: Take ~500ms to run, while `xset q` only takes 300

Answer (score 4):

I wrote [xdpyprobe](https://github.com/alezost/xdpyprobe) program which is intended for this purpose.  Unlike xset, xdpyinfo and other general tools, it does not do any extra actions (just checks X server and exits) and it may not produce any output (if "-q" option is specified).

Answer (score 4):

The bash script solution:

```
if ! xset q &>/dev/null; then
    echo "No X server at \$DISPLAY [$DISPLAY]" >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

Doesn't work if you login from another console (Ctrl+Alt+F?) or ssh. For me this solution works in my Archlinux:

```
#!/bin/sh
ps aux|grep -v grep|grep "/usr/lib/Xorg"
EXITSTATUS=$?
if [ $EXITSTATUS -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "X server running"
  exit 1
fi
```

You can change /usr/lib/Xorg for only Xorg or the proper command on your system.

Comment: in my case the process name was `/usr/lib/xorg/Xorg` instead of `/usr/lib/Xorg`

Answer (score 2):

1)

```
# netstat -lp|grep -i x
tcp        0      0 *:x11                   *:*                     LISTEN      2937/X          
tcp6       0      0 [::]:x11                [::]:*                  LISTEN      2937/X          
Active UNIX domain sockets (only servers)
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     8940     2937/X              @/tmp/.X11-unix/X0
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     8941     2937/X              /tmp/.X11-unix/X0
#
```

2) nmap

```
# nmap localhost|grep -i x
6000/tcp open  X11
#
```

Answer (score 2):

First you need to ensure foundational X11 packages are correctly installed on your server:

```
rpm -qa | grep xorg-x11-xauth
```

If not then, kindly install all packages :

```
sudo yum install xorg-x11-xauth xterm
```

Ensure that openssh server is configured to forward x11 connections :

```
edit file : vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config

X11Forwarding yes
```

NOTE : If that line is preceded by a comment (#) or is set to no, update the file to match the above, and restart your ssh server daemon (be careful here — if you made an error you may lock yourself out of the server)

```
sudo /etc/init.d/sshd restart
```

Now, configure SSH application to forward X11 requests :

```
ssh -Y your_username@your_server.your_domain.com
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if [[ $DISPLAY ]]; then 
  …
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

This is PHP script for checking.

```
$xsession = `pidof X`;
if (!$xsession) {
    echo "There is no active X session, aborting..\n";
    exit;
}
```

Similar command can be used in shell script too. like the pidof command.