# How to strace for X11 output "connect /tmp/.X11-unix/X1: No such file or directory"

Tags: bash, x11

I want to *silently* test whether X11 is working, from a script.

I keep getting "connect /tmp/.X11-unix/X1: No such file or directory", even if I redirect stdout and stderr to /dev/null with (for example) `xset q > /dev/null 2>&1`

I strace'd, and it doesn't appear to be getting written by xset. I also strace'd the relevant sshd and it doesn't seem to be writing it either.

xset, xdpyinfo and the test program at [How to check if X server is running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637005/how-to-check-if-x-server-is-running) all output this useless error message. In fact, so does vim. But "ls" does not.

I also tried: `script -e -c 'xset q' /dev/null > /dev/null 2>&1`
...but even that outputs the error message.

What do I need to do to silence this overaggressive error message?

Thanks!

PS: Here's an strace of xset q:

```
20878 execve("/usr/bin/xset", ["xset", "q"], 0x7ffe3e91cfe0 /* 33 vars */) = 0
20878 brk(NULL)                         = 0x563d8a664000
20878 access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
20878 access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
20878 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
20878 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=141841, ...}) = 0
20878 mmap(NULL, 141841, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f19ac118000
20878 close(3)                          = 0
20878 access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
20878 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXmuu.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
20878 read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0p\23\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
20878 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=14528, ...}) = 0
20878 mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f19ac144000
20878 mmap(NULL, 2109592, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f19abd10000
20878 mprotect(0x7f19abd13000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
20878 mmap(0x7f19abf12000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2000) = 0x7f19abf12000
20878 close(3)                          = 0
20878 access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
20878 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
20878 read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\2205\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
20878 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=73640, ...}) = 0
20878 mmap(NULL, 2169496, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f19abaf8000
20878 mprotect(0x7f19abb09000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
20878 mmap(0x7f19abd08000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x10000) = 0x7f19abd08000
20878 close(3)                          = 0
20878 access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
20878 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
20878 read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\300\207\1\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
20878 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1277384, ...}) = 0
20878 mmap(NULL, 3374392, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f19ab7c0000
20878 mprotect(0x7f19ab8f3000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
20878 mmap(0x7f19abaf3000, 20480, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x133000) = 0x7f19abaf3000
20878 close(3)                          = 0
20878 access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
20878 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
20878 read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\260\34\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
20878 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=2030544, ...}) = 0
20878 mmap(NULL, 4131552, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f19ab3c8000
20878 mprotect(0x7f19ab5af000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
20878 mmap(0x7f19ab7af000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1e7000) = 0x7f19ab7af000
20878 mmap(0x7f19ab7b5000, 15072, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f19ab7b5000
20878 close(3)                          = 0
20878 access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
20878 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
20878 read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0P\261\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
20878 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=162232, ...}) = 0
20878 mmap(NULL, 2257576, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f19ab1a0000
20878 mprotect(0x7f19ab1c6000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
20878 mmap(0x7f19ab3c6000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x26000) = 0x7f19ab3c6000
20878 close(3)                          = 0
20878 access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
20878 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
20878 read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0P\16\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
20878 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=14560, ...}) = 0
20878 mmap(NULL, 2109712, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f19aaf98000
20878 mprotect(0x7f19aaf9b000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
20878 mmap(0x7f19ab19a000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2000) = 0x7f19ab19a000
20878 close(3)                          = 0
20878 access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
20878 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
20878 read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0P\16\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
20878 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=14456, ...}) = 0
20878 mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f19ac142000
20878 mmap(NULL, 2109720, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f19aad90000
20878 mprotect(0x7f19aad92000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
20878 mmap(0x7f19aaf92000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2000) = 0x7f19aaf92000
20878 close(3)                          = 0
20878 access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
20878 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
20878 read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\20\21\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
20878 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=22616, ...}) = 0
20878 mmap(NULL, 2117760, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f19aab88000
20878 mprotect(0x7f19aab8d000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
20878 mmap(0x7f19aad8c000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x4000) = 0x7f19aad8c000
20878 close(3)                          = 0
20878 access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
20878 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
20878 read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0P4\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
20878 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=80104, ...}) = 0
20878 mmap(NULL, 2179152, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f19aa970000
20878 mprotect(0x7f19aa983000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
20878 mmap(0x7f19aab82000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x12000) = 0x7f19aab82000
20878 mmap(0x7f19aab84000, 80, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f19aab84000
20878 close(3)                          = 0
20878 access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
20878 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
20878 read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\0\"\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
20878 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=31680, ...}) = 0
20878 mmap(NULL, 2128864, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f19aa768000
20878 mprotect(0x7f19aa76f000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
20878 mmap(0x7f19aa96e000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x6000) = 0x7f19aa96e000
20878 close(3)                          = 0
20878 access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
20878 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
20878 read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0000b\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
20878 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=144976, ...}) = 0
20878 mmap(NULL, 2221184, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f19aa548000
20878 mprotect(0x7f19aa562000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
20878 mmap(0x7f19aa761000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x19000) = 0x7f19aa761000
20878 mmap(0x7f19aa763000, 13440, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f19aa763000
20878 close(3)                          = 0
20878 mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f19ac13d000
20878 mmap(NULL, 12288, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f19ac115000
20878 arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f19ac115740) = 0
20878 mprotect(0x7f19ab7af000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
20878 mprotect(0x7f19aa761000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
20878 mprotect(0x7f19aa96e000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
20878 mprotect(0x7f19aab82000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
20878 mprotect(0x7f19aad8c000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
20878 mprotect(0x7f19aaf92000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
20878 mprotect(0x7f19ab19a000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
20878 mprotect(0x7f19ab3c6000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
20878 mprotect(0x7f19abaf3000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
20878 mprotect(0x7f19abd08000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
20878 mprotect(0x7f19abf12000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
20878 mprotect(0x563d8872f000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
20878 mprotect(0x7f19ac13f000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
20878 munmap(0x7f19ac118000, 141841)    = 0
20878 set_tid_address(0x7f19ac115a10)   = 20878
20878 set_robust_list(0x7f19ac115a20, 24) = 0
20878 rt_sigaction(SIGRTMIN, {sa_handler=0x7f19aa54dcb0, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, sa_restorer=0x7f19aa55a890}, NULL, 8) = 0
20878 rt_sigaction(SIGRT_1, {sa_handler=0x7f19aa54dd50, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, sa_restorer=0x7f19aa55a890}, NULL, 8) = 0
20878 rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [RTMIN RT_1], NULL, 8) = 0
20878 prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_STACK, NULL, {rlim_cur=8192*1024, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}) = 0
20878 brk(NULL)                         = 0x563d8a664000
20878 brk(0x563d8a685000)               = 0x563d8a685000
20878 socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK, 0) = 3
20878 connect(3, {sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="/var/run/nscd/socket"}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
20878 close(3)                          = 0
20878 socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK, 0) = 3
20878 connect(3, {sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="/var/run/nscd/socket"}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
20878 close(3)                          = 0
20878 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/nsswitch.conf", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
20878 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=529, ...}) = 0
20878 read(3, "# /etc/nsswitch.conf\n#\n# Example"..., 4096) = 529
20878 read(3, "", 4096)                 = 0
20878 close(3)                          = 0
20878 stat("/etc/resolv.conf", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=304, ...}) = 0
20878 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/host.conf", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
20878 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=92, ...}) = 0
20878 read(3, "# The \"order\" line is only used "..., 4096) = 92
20878 read(3, "", 4096)                 = 0
20878 close(3)                          = 0
20878 futex(0x7f19ab7b7ba4, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
20878 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/resolv.conf", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
20878 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=304, ...}) = 0
20878 read(3, "# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file fo"..., 4096) = 304
20878 read(3, "", 4096)                 = 0
20878 close(3)                          = 0
20878 uname({sysname="Linux", nodename="zareason-limbo", ...}) = 0
20878 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
20878 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=141841, ...}) = 0
20878 mmap(NULL, 141841, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f19ac0f0000
20878 close(3)                          = 0
20878 access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
20878 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
20878 read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0P#\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
20878 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=47568, ...}) = 0
20878 mmap(NULL, 2168632, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f19aa330000
20878 mprotect(0x7f19aa33b000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
20878 mmap(0x7f19aa53a000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0xa000) = 0x7f19aa53a000
20878 mmap(0x7f19aa53c000, 22328, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f19aa53c000
20878 close(3)                          = 0
20878 mprotect(0x7f19aa53a000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
20878 munmap(0x7f19ac0f0000, 141841)    = 0
20878 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/hosts", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
20878 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=403, ...}) = 0
20878 read(3, "127.0.0.1\tlocalhost\n127.0.1.1\tza"..., 4096) = 403
20878 read(3, "", 4096)                 = 0
20878 close(3)                          = 0
20878 socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC, IPPROTO_TCP) = 3
20878 setsockopt(3, SOL_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, [1], 4) = 0
20878 setsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, [1], 4) = 0
20878 connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(6013), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, 16) = 0
20878 getpeername(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(6013), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, [124->16]) = 0
20878 uname({sysname="Linux", nodename="zareason-limbo", ...}) = 0
20878 access("/home/dstromberg/.Xauthority", R_OK) = 0
20878 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/dstromberg/.Xauthority", O_RDONLY) = 4
20878 fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0600, st_size=827, ...}) = 0
20878 read(4, "\1\0\0\16zareason-limbo\0\0010\0\22MIT-MAGIC"..., 4096) = 827
20878 read(4, "", 4096)                 = 0
20878 close(4)                          = 0
20878 getsockname(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(37214), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, [124->16]) = 0
20878 fcntl(3, F_GETFL)                 = 0x2 (flags O_RDWR)
20878 fcntl(3, F_SETFL, O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK) = 0
20878 fcntl(3, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)     = 0
20878 poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, -1) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLOUT}])
20878 writev(3, [{iov_base="l\0\v\0\0\0\22\0\20\0\0\0", iov_len=12}, {iov_base="", iov_len=0}, {iov_base="MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1", iov_len=18}, {iov_base="\0\0", iov_len=2}, {iov_base="\256b\245\317f\262\25\254\27\365!H\212\3316J", iov_len=16}, {iov_base="", iov_len=0}], 6) = 48
20878 recvfrom(3, 0x563d8a6660e0, 8, 0, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
20878 poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}], 1, -1) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLIN|POLLERR|POLLHUP}])
20878 recvfrom(3, 0x563d8a6660e0, 8, 0, NULL, NULL) = -1 ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)
20878 shutdown(3, SHUT_RDWR)            = -1 ENOTCONN (Transport endpoint is not connected)
20878 close(3)                          = 0
20878 write(2, "xset:  unable to open display \"l"..., 47) = 47
20878 exit_group(1)                     = ?
20878 +++ exited with 1 +++
```

And here's a type -a xset:

```
$ type -a xset
below cmd output started 2019 Sun Jun 30 07:49:33 AM PDT
xset is /usr/bin/xset
```

Running without redirection, to show the order of the messages:

```
$ xset q
below cmd output started 2019 Sun Jun 30 08:03:24 AM PDT
connect /tmp/.X11-unix/X1: No such file or directory
xset:  unable to open display "localhost:13.0"
```

In response to a comment from melpomene, I set up a test account with no startup files at all.  I then ssh -Y'd to it, sudo'd, and got the same error message as described above.

I had been testing in gnome-terminal exclusively.  I just tried konsole and again got the offending error message.

I just tried strace'ing the openssh client; it produced a single occurrence of the string "connect", which did not look relevant (other than connecting to the ssh server).

I had been testing exclusively on a Linux Mint 19.1 system. I just tried it on a freshly-installed Debian 9.9 system, and got the same result.

Steps to replicate:

1. ssh -Y remote.host.example.com
2. sudo bash
3. xset -q > /dev/null 2>&1

You may see the offending error message after these 3 simple steps.

Comment: What's in your strace log? Also, what does `type -a xset` report?

Comment: "*below cmd output started 2019 Sun Jun 30 07:49:33 AM PDT*"? Where did that come from?

Comment: The strace log shows that `xset` is producing the error message `xset:  unable to open display ...`. Does that happen before or after the *connect* thing?

Comment: "below cmd output" is from bash $PS0.

Comment: What if you `strace -f bash` and run `xset q` from there? Does the connect message show up in the log then?

Comment: No, strace'ing bash -c 'xset q' doesn't show any interesting write's nor does it show any interesting occurrences of "connect".

Comment: Might be something in your `~/.bashrc`, then. That's why I said to run `xset q` from `bash` manually and not use `-c`.

Comment: Same thing interactively: strace reveals no interesting write's, no interesting occurrences of "connect".

Comment: I wouldn't use `strace` for this task at all. Use `sysdig` -- it can track *every job on the system* at the same time with minimal overhead, to tell you which one is doing the write (and to which FD).

Comment: `sysdig 'evt.buffer contains "connect /tmp/.X11-unix"'` and there you are -- the only results will be processes reading or writing that string. (Of course, if it's split into more than one write call, you may need to loosen the filter).

Comment: This is the first time I've heard of sysdig.  sysdig 'evt.buffer contains "connect /tmp/.X11-unix"' returned nothing. Neither did checking for just X11-unix.

Comment: Running your sysdig on the ssh client machine, I get just: 6660206 10:38:09.520806402 1 ssh (29440) < write res=54 data=connect /tmp/.X11-unix/X1: No such file or directory.. 
6660237 10:38:09.520967273 2 mate-terminal (11998) < read res=55 data=.connect /tmp/.X11-unix/X1: No such file or directory..

Comment: Possibly related to the issue here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57138/why-does-my-x11-forwarding-attempt-fail-with-connect-tmp-x11-unix-x0-no-such ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is pretty easy to understand and replicate, but there is a number of moving parts.

We ssh to a remote machine with X forwarding. **This ssh process must have access to a working X server locally.** Here we'll start it up with a joke `$DISPLAY`:

```
(local) $ DISPLAY=:87 ssh -Y remote
Warning: No xauth data; using fake authentication data for X11 forwarding
```

That `Warning` is an indication that *ssh* cannot contact a working X server locally.

On *remote* `$DISPLAY` is not `:87`

```
(remote) $ echo $DISPLAY
(remote) localhost:11.0
```

This is the magic that *ssh*'s `-Y` does and how its X11 proxy works.

We run a command on remote that tries to connect to `$DISPLAY`:

```
(remote) $ xset -q
connect /tmp/.X11-unix/X99: No such file or directory
xset:  unable to open display "localhost:11.0"
```

And here is your problem:

```
(remote) $ xset -q >/dev/null 2>&1
connect /tmp/.X11-unix/X99: No such file or directory
```

The `unable` error message was being printed by *xset*,
and has been redirected away.
However the `connect` error message is coming out of *ssh*.
Remember that *xset* runs on *remote*,
while *ssh* is running on *local*.

You need to validate `$DISPLAY` on *local* *before* running *ssh*.

You can quieten *ssh* in a number of ways,
but I'm not a fan of throwing away error messages.
One way would be to reduce the error verbosity:

```
(local) $ DISPLAY=:87 ssh -Y -o LogLevel=FATAL remote 'xset -q &>/dev/null'
```

See *man ssh_config* for a list of *ssh* settings.

Comment: Accepted.  The followup question: Why doesn't sysdig see it?

Comment: @dstromberg _sysdig_? Assuming you meant _strace_. You say that you straced the ssh server _sshd_. You need to strace the ssh client running on local, _ssh_.

Comment: Shouldn't both strace and sysdig see it?

Comment: @dstromberg _strace_ will see it when you run it on the ssh client command (_ssh_). It won't see it when you run it on the ssh server command (_sshd_).